Raycasters drifting off to far NDC
At the moment I am working with Cesium and OpenBIM Library to set up a viewer that can combine GIS and BIM information.
For this approach, I need to control my BIM viewer by synchronising it with my GIS controller. The other day I started working on Raycasting to gather element information from my IFC models, so I am only using the Cesium controller, but I ran into a problem. I have to disable pointer events in order to "synchronise" the camera controls. This prevents me from using the generic raycaster from ThreeJS or OpenBIM, so I had to create my own logic.
After some testing I ended up with something like a raycaster but with some problems.  After researching the ThreeJS raycaster, I found a fairly simple way to "cast" a ray through the ScreenSpace using the NDC with my mouse pointer. The only problem... when I use this method I end up not hitting elements that are displayed in edge areas of my screen because my ray cast to the far NDC (Normalised Device Coordinate) plane causes something like a drift. (You can see this in the uploaded video).
Can anyone enlighten me about

Raycasters in general?

How they are programmed for OpenBIM components?

What am I missing here?


I appreciate anyone commenting on this and helping me to move forward with my project.  
Uploaded Building
[Watching Rays from another perspective][Casting Rays from Camera perspective]

Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.
